# OpenCL, problem with vector types: cross product is not working as I expect

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I am newbie to *OpenCL* as well as heavy parallel computing. I came across a problem with operations over vector types.
I am crazy about taking advantage of **SIMD** instructions for operations with vectors and matrices. But the problem is that vector types, float `float3` may be not working as I expect...
The thing is quite simple I just need to make my function to the cross product of two vectors.

I've written version of that function in Scala and it's working perfectly.

Here is the code in Scala:

```
    @inline def crossProduct(other: Vector3D) = Vector3D(
        y * other.z - z * other.y,
        z * other.x - x * other.z,
        x * other.y - y * other.x)
```

---

And this one is version in OpenCL and fails the test:

```c
float3 cross_pro(float3 a, float3 b) {
    return (float3) (
        (a.y * b.z) - (a.z * b.y), 
        (a.z * b.x) - (a.x * b.z),
        (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * a.x));
}
```

Given set of parameters: `cross_pro((float3) (0, 1, 0), (float3) (1, 0, 0));`
Online calculators say that the result must be `(float3) (0, 0, -1)`
but OpenCL version prints: `(float3) (0, 0, 0)`!
 I can not even imagine why it happens? so I checked this function for overloading, experimented with these vector types an did so many other stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(a.x * b.y) - (a.y * a.x));
```

should be

```
(a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x));
```

also OpenCL has cross product already

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/cross.html

```
float4 cross (float4 p0,float4 p1)
float3 cross (float3 p0,float3 p1)

double4 cross(double4 p0,double4 p1)   // if double extension enabled                               
double3 cross(double3 p0,double3 p1)   // if double extension enabled 

half4 cross(half4 p0,half4 p1)   // if half extension enabled                               
half3 cross(half3 p0,half3 p1)   // if half extension enabled
```

> **Description**
>
> Returns the cross product of p0.xyz and p1.xyz. The w component of the
>   float4 result (or double or half if the cl_khr_fp64 or cl_khr_fp16
>   extensions are enabled) will be 0.0.

If you need SIMD performance of a CPU: I guess, drivers will handle any available CPU cross product or dot product-like functions efficiently if you use their cross product function definition.